# Which file is an anonymous memory mapping mapped to in linux?

Tags: c, linux, ipc, mmap

My question is, when we create an **anonymous memory mapping**, what is the file that is being mapped into the address space of the process. I know that an anonymous mapping is guaranteed to be filled with zeros. Is it then the **/dev/zero** file? From what I understand, Inter Process Communication is not possible until there is some file that is being mapped inside the participating processes' address spaces ... be it a file in **tmpfs** or in the normal file system. I am new to Inter Process Communication, if you find any flaw in my understanding, please rectify.

Comment: You can't write to /dev/zero.  An anonymous mmap has no file backing.

Comment: @stark Surprisingly, `mmap`ing `/dev/zero` actually does produce a useful map that works just like an anonymous one.

Comment: @stark Well, it must map to something right. Otherwise how is IPC between a Parent and Chlid process achieved. The Child can't access the parent's address space directly .... or can it ?

Answer (score 2):

From `man mmap`:

> **`MAP_ANONYMOUS`**
>
> The mapping is not backed by any file; [...]

It just allocates and initializes the memory. Before calling `mmap`, you would get a protection violation (SIGSEGV) trying to access the memory since the virtual memory wasn't mapped to real memory. (Well, that's what happens in system with virtual memory.)

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, when we create an anonymous memory mapping, what is the file that is being mapped into the address space of the process.

There is no file.

> I know that an anonymous mapping is guaranteed to be filled with zeros. Is it then the /dev/zero file?

No.

Historically, though, the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag is a newer invention than `mmap` itself.  Prior to that, if you wanted a chunk of memory filled with zeros and not backed by any regular file, you would indeed open `/dev/zero` and mmap it.  This was handled as a special case by the OS and would effectively give you an anonymous mapping; different processes creating mappings of `/dev/zero` wouldn't see each others' data, even if they used `MAP_SHARED`.  I believe the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag was introduced to simplify this process and avoid the extra system calls for opening and closing `/dev/zero`.

> From what I understand, Inter Process Communication is not possible until there is some file that is being mapped inside the participating processes' address spaces ... be it a file in tmpfs or in the normal file system.

Well, that's not true; `MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED` is a counterexample to that. If your process creates a mapping with `MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED`, then any children created with `fork()` after that point (and their children, and so on) will inherit the mapping, and the memory will be shared between all of them and the parent.  Any writes to that memory by any of those processes will be seen by all of them.

This does mean you can only use this for IPC between "related" processes, descendants of the common ancestor who created the mapping (unless there are clever tricks I'm not aware of to give access to unrelated processes).  Mapping an actual file (other than `/dev/zero`) doesn't have this restriction.

And of course there are other IPC mechanisms that don't involve files at all, e.g. POSIX shared memory (`shmget` and friends).

Comment: So how does an anonymous mapping work for a Parent and a Child. Does the Child have access to the address space of the Parent ?

Comment: @ShayakSarkar: The child returns from `fork()` with an exact copy of the parent's address space.  Most of it is copy-on-write, so that later changes made by one process are not seen by the other.  But shared mmaps, including anonymous ones, are in fact shared; writes made by the child can be read by the parent, and vice versa.  It's a matter of perspective whether this is the child having access to the parent's address space, or vice versa, or neither.